# How to loop over Typescript Array in ReactJS?

Tags: arrays, reactjs, typescript

Error:

> Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'.ts(2322)

> index.d.ts(1354, 9): The expected type comes from property 'children' which is declared here on type 'DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes, HTMLDivElement>'

Code:

```
interface Item{
  item: string;
  type: string;
  answer: string;
  answers: Array<any>;
}    

interface Props {
      items: Item[];
}

//this is the line where the error is being stated
this.props.items[0].answers.forEach((item) => console.log(item));
```

All I'm trying to do is loop over the array and log it out. the array can be numbers/strings.

I've trying spreading the props array out into it's own instance of an array, and the same error happens.

Comment: Please provide rest of your code. Your code alone does not result in such error

Answer (score 0):

You have not posted enough code to be 100% sure, but I would say that you are not returning JSX from your React component. Try adding

```js
return null;
```

to the bottom of your react component and see if that helps